# Xml data deserialization

Tags: c#, xml

I have I question for you. I want to read XML data but in specific way and I dont know hot to deal with it. I will be very happy for your recommendations.

Imagine that I have XML like in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAbstractData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- COMMON PART -->
  <AbstractData xsi:type="Test1Data">
    <Enable>true</Enable>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Count>3</Count>
    <Debug>false</Debug>
    <Error>true</Error>
    <Info>
      .....
    </Info>

    <!-- SPECIFIC PART -->

    .....

  </AbstractData>
  <AbstractData xsi:type="Test2Data">
    <!-- COMMON PART -->
    <Enable>true</Enable>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Count>3</Count>
    <Debug>false</Debug>
    <Error>false</Error>
    <Info>
      .....
    </Info>

    <!-- SPECIFIC PART -->

    .....

  </AbstractData>
  <AbstractData xsi:type="Test3Data">
    <!-- COMMON PART -->
    <Enable>true</Enable>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Count>3</Count>
    <Debug>false</Debug>
    <Error>true</Error>
    <Info>
      .....
    </Info>

    <!-- SPECIFIC PART -->

    .....

  </AbstractData>
</ArrayOfAbstractData>
```

As you can see, Im serializing 3 different objects in List. These objects have common base class called AbstractData.

Now I want to read these data but in very specific way. First I want to read only common part (properties of abstract class). Based on these properties I will decide whether class Test1Data, Test2Data, ... are well known or not. If they are well known I will red the rest of the XML file. Simply I want to avoid using XmlInclude in Abstract Base class because Im using it with plugin system and not every single class will be known in time of deserialization.

Hope you understood my intention.

Thanks for your recommendations

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. When you post a question about some code you have written not working, you need to provide three things. 1. The behaviour you are seeing and why you think it's wrong, 2. The minimum code and/or steps necessary to demonstrate the behaviour you are seeing, and 3. The behaviour you would like to see. Unless you provide these things it's very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks but I dont need code. I came here only for idea how to do it. I explained my intention about what I want to do and what Im trying to avoid (XmlInclude). Im perfectly able to read this Xml, but only when classes like Test1Data, Test2Data, ... are known. Code is not needed. Im not able to read base class properties (common part) when child class (specific part) is unknown.

Comment: REading xml files can be done using a number of different methods.  You can use serialization which can read the entire or part of an xml file and store data into classes.  You need to define the classes before using this method.  Which I recommend for the common data.  You can then use XmlDocument class or XDocument class to read the optional section of the xml.

Comment: Ok thanks I solved it. First I read common part using XDocument and when I decided that Type of class is know I deserialized whole class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XmlInclude` attribute to specify all possible types.

```
public class ArrayOfAbstractData
{
    [XmlElement("AbstractData")]
    public AbstractData[] AbstractData { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(Test1Data))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Test2Data))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Test3Data))]
public class AbstractData
{
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public byte Count { get; set; }
    public bool Debug { get; set; }
    public bool Error { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class Test1Data : AbstractData
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Test2Data : AbstractData
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Test3Data : AbstractData
{
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

It should work.

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfAbstractData));

ArrayOfAbstractData arr;

using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    arr = (ArrayOfAbstractData)xs.Deserialize(fs);

foreach (var x in arr.AbstractData)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly what I wanted to avoid :). I wont to know every single type that will be  saved in XML. Of course in that case it would be easy. I Already solved the problem. See my comment above